# SQL Query text formation logic after where condition

Tags: java, sql, logic

i need to generate a SQL Query using logic implemented in java, After WHERE conditions there can be multiple comparitions using AND OR NOT, eg:

```
WHERE column1 = 'xyz' 
and column2 = 2 or column1 = 'abc' 
and column2 = 1 and column4 IN(SUBQUERY1 condition) or column4 IN(SUBQUERY1 condition)
```

This can be re-write as

```
WHERE column1 IN('xyz','abc') and column2 ..... ??
and column4 IN(SUBQUERY1 IN OR NOT OR AND)
```

tell me the logic how to group them properly to form a query.

Thanks
Prasanth

Comment: yes forgot to mention. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should wrap your condition by `()` to make each condition is properly.

```
WHERE column1 = 'xyz' 
and (column2 = 2 or column1 = 'abc') 
and ((column2 = 1 and column4 IN(SUBQUERY1 condition)) or column4 IN(SUBQUERY1 condition))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any help @Prasanth Kumar K

Comment: hi .. Thanks for answering, but i need write a program to identify conditions and place as text accordingly